# Three js - Textures Loading - async / await

Tags: javascript, async-await, three.js, loader, image-size

I did a Drawing class:

```javascript
export class Drawing {
    constructor(texture) {        
        const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            map: texture
        });
        this.mesh = new Mesh(new PlaneGeometry(texture.image.naturalWidth / 20, texture.image.naturalHeight / 20), material);
    }

    setPosition(x, y, z) {
        this.mesh.position.x = x;
        this.mesh.position.y = y;
        this.mesh.position.z = z;
    }
}
```

I would like to access the texture.image properties in order to set the PlaneGeometry. So, before invoking a Drawing object, I do some async/await calls to load the textures (the Drawing invokations are made in the World constructor):

```javascript
let world;
let raycasterDown;
let prevTime = performance.now();
const direction = new Vector3();
const globalInputs = new GlobalInputs();
const textureLoader = new TextureLoader();

const promiseTextureBack = (pathName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(textureLoader.load(pathName));
    });
}

const allTexturesPromises = [];
drawingPaths.map(pathName => {          //drawingPaths is an array of string
    allTexturesPromises.push(promiseTextureBack(pathName));
});

const loadingWorld = async () => {
    const allTextures = await Promise.all(allTexturesPromises); 
    console.log(allTextures[0]);
    world = new World(allTextures);
    document.body.appendChild(world.renderer.domElement);
    world.instructions.addEventListener('click', function () {
        world.controls.lock();
    });
    world.controls.addEventListener('lock', function () {
        world.instructions.style.display = 'none';
        world.blocker.style.display = 'none';
    });

    world.controls.addEventListener('unlock', function () {
        world.blocker.style.display = 'block';
        world.instructions.style.display = '';
    });
}

init();

function init() {
    loadingWorld();
    raycasterDown = new Raycaster(new Vector3(), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), 0, 10);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        globalInputs.onKeyDown(event);
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        globalInputs.onKeyUp(event);
    });
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
    animate();
}
```

Nevertheless,

```javascript
    console.log(allTextures[0])
```

in the loadingWorld returns:

[image]

And the image is still undefined... I'm quite sure the issue comes from:

```javascript
textureLoader.load(pathName)
```

I'm open to any suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`load` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader.load) takes a callback. It doesn't return anything that you can call `resolve` with. Instead of all this `promiseTextureBack` code, just use the [`loadAsync` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync) which returns a promise:

```
const allTexturesPromises = drawingPaths.map(pathName => {  
    return textureLoader.load(pathName);
});
```

Comment: You made my day ! Thanks !